# 3d object visible in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I'm playing around 3d objects in WPF. I have a viewport3d. This contains two 3d object (ModelVisual3d) named "A" and "B".

I want to just show A and hide B,

sometimes, I want to just show B and hide A.

`How can I do hide it?`

I'm found answer, but this tell "set the OffsetX property to 1000.". I don't like it.

`Is it possible to hide object?`

Answer (score 1):

Are you working only with xaml?
You could just remove the ModelVisual3D object from the viewport and add them when you need want them visible. Like:

```
Visual3D A = ...
Visual3D B = ...
// invisible A, visible B
viewport3d.children.remove(A)
viewport3d.children.add(B)
// visible A, invisible B
viewport3d.children.add(A)
viewport3d.children.remove(B)
```

Just make sure you keep the A (and B) reference somehow.